# DB or XML Question

Tags: xml, database

XML seems to be another way to store information in a much smaller scale? While DB can handle all sorts. I'm interested in knowing what are the pro's and con's to the each. Is one of them better in a scenario? I'm sure each has there best case scenario.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... XML is a file that anyone can read, since it's text.

A database must be accessed through an API, and conforms to certain database-ey structures.

You can make XML that's like a database, or make it different, too.

You can probably prove that informationally they're equivalent, XML schema to Database schema.

In practice you'll want to write an appropriate API to your particular XML structure. But others could read the schema and do their own...

Databases shine because they usually have an API that lots of agents can access safely simultaneously. XML, by itself, is just a text file.

Comment: That's database server that you can access simultaneously, it has nothing to do with db files in regard to XML files. XML Schema doesn't come even close to DB schema. There are API's for XML, exactly because it is not "just a text file", it is a STRUCTURED text file. I can go and on.

Comment: @Elijah, I love XML, and agree it's a huge value-add over a text-file... So I'm being a little coy by saying "just a text file." Mostly just emphasizing that it is a text file at all. I do think that with enough "extra rules" you can do all database-ey stuff with XML; but I stand corrected that DTD or schema alone doesn't really encompass DB schemas. Now that you point it out. :)

Comment: And what are your options with XML for joining, indexing, relationship definition, uniqueness, searchability etc? The answer is easy - none. XML is a structured file. Full stop.

Answer (score 2):

XML is great for storing static data, like configuration files.  It can be read from very easily and quickly with existing APIs and/or XPath.  However, since it is simply a file it should be used only for storing data that will be read and not require updates from the application your users will use.  Depending on your OS, file locking and privileges may be an issue for updates and concurrency could be a logistical nightmare to maintain.

Databases are collections of records that can be read, updated, or deleted with ease.  For large datasets, databases also provide the ability to index fields to improve performance and to setup different schema or views to control the visibility of records for different types of users.  Data integrity can more easily be maintained with a database as well.

In summary, XML is better suited for small to medium datasets that will not need to change often and are read-only from the application.  Databases are better suited for dynamic or large datasets or where security of the data may be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well XML vs DB has been covered a lot by all the smart people you care to name including the Man himself. Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html things will become clearer.

Comment: Explain the down vote. I dont mind the repo, I want to know whether the person actually disagrees and why.

Comment: SO attempts to be a repository of searchable answers, answers of the form "click on this link and read someone else's answer" are discouraged.

Comment: I agree with your statement. Even though quoting Joel is like pointing the FAQ.

Comment: Though one would only disagree with Joel's article if he'd not read it. And I do encourage everyone to go an read it.

Comment: So he gave the answer but Elijah doesn't like how he gave the answer. Sounds like personal preference to me.

Comment: Actually what he said is true. SO does attempt to collect knowledge. But that's ok, when it comes to a personal opinion or implementation etc. In this particular case I didn't see the point in replicating the bytes of text on a topic that has been extensively covered.